# JWTAuth::user() returns null

Tags: laravel, jwt, token

I am using Laravel 8 and JWTAuth package for the api requests, **often** the request throws error when trying to access user info with the following line:

```
JWTAuth::user()->id
```

The error: 500 Internal Server Error

```
ErrorException: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object ...
```

The only way I could resolve this, temporary however, is to refresh the token. **I am wondering that if token is expired it should say token is expired, but seems something else is happening here**, which I could not figure it out.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Although I am on it currently, I am trying to use some of the functions like JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()  and JWTAuth::toUser(JWTAuth::getToken()) to get some clue, this is where I got so far. I will update once I found something worthy :) @Nico Hasse

Comment: You are not authenticated?

Comment: @Espresso I understand, and I expect a message like token is invalid or expired than this error.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else facing this issue, working with tokens can quickly create caching issues which can cause headaches if not considered. So in my case resetting the JWT secrete keys fixed the issue.

```
php artisan jwt:secret
```

Also for clearing most of the cached sections:

```
php artisan config:clear && php artisan cache:clear && composer dump-autoload && php artisan view:clear && php artisan route:clear && npm cache clean --force
```